# C# Bot Framework Registration

Tags: botframework, bots

I am trying to determine if all .NET Framework bots need to be registered on https://dev.botframework.com? Do all convesations actually travel through dev.botframework.com? My company would have a bear with this.

Comment: They don't necessarily have to be registered there since you can create on in the Azure Portal. But, yes, they will be shown on that site once you log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Bot Framework Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator) and develop a bot using node or .net without registering.  However, if you want to connect to a channel (Facebook Messenger, Skype, Telegram, Direct Line, etc) then you will need to register the bot on Azure.  Azure hosts the channel connectors that translate messages from native channel format to the Activity Schema used by the Bot Framework.

That said, there are some community efforts towards enabling bot communication without registering: https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline  There are many limitations though.